# How to wait inquirer answer to be processed (by fs.writeFile) before continuing asynchronously

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs, inquirer

So I have this asynchronous function with inquirer and fs.writeFile inside

```js
(async () => {

...

  if (process.env.IG_USERNAME && process.env.IG_PASSWORD) {
    console.log(`Used as ${chalk.green(process.env.IG_USERNAME)}`);
  } else {
    console.log(`\nInstagram account data is not yet put in \nInputting in...`);

    await inquirer.prompt(questions).then((answers) => {
      let file = `IG_USERNAME=${answers.username}\nIG_PASSWORD=${answers.password}\n#ONLINE_MODE=true`;
      fs.writeFile(".env", file, (err) => {
        if (err) console.log("Something went wrong..");
        else console.log(`Used as ${chalk.green(process.env.IG_USERNAME)}`);
      });
    });
  }

  await login();

...

})();
```

the `login();` function needs the .env variable, i input it using inquirer but the `login();` function get executed before the inquirer answer get processed.

What should I do to make the `login();` waits until the `fs.writeFile` is finished?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally either use `.then()` or `await` with promises, not both together. And `login()` is getting executed before because the promise is getting resolved via `.then()`.

And there is no promise returned to `await` for before calling `login()`.

**Solution 1:** The quick fix is to resolve `await login();` inside the callback of `fs.writeFile`, but then login()'s error would have to be handled as well, which just makes the code more verbose to begin with.

```
const answers = await inquirer.prompt(questions);
let file = `IG_USERNAME=${answers.username}\nIG_PASSWORD=${answers.password}\n#ONLINE_MODE=true`;
fs.writeFile(".env", file, async (err) => {
  if (err) console.error("Error:fs.writeFile()::", err);
  else console.log(`Used as ${chalk.green(process.env.IG_USERNAME)}`);
  try {
    await login();
  } catch (e) {
    console.error("Error::login():", e);
  }
});
```

**Solution 2:** **`util.promisify`** with Node >= V8

Make the `fs.writeFile` to a promise.

```
const fs = require("fs");
const { promisify } = require("util");
const promisedWriteFile = promisify(fs.writeFile);

try {
  const answers = await inquirer.prompt(questions);
  let file = `IG_USERNAME=${answers.username}\nIG_PASSWORD=${answers.password}\n#ONLINE_MODE=true`;
  await promisedWriteFile(".env", file);
  await login();
} catch (error) {
  console.error("Any error::", error);
}
```

**Solution 3:** **fs Promises API** with Node >= V10

```
try {
  const answers = await inquirer.prompt(questions);
  let file = `IG_USERNAME=${answers.username}\nIG_PASSWORD=${answers.password}\n#ONLINE_MODE=true`;
  await fs.promises.writeFile(".env", file);
  await login();
} catch (error) {
  console.error("Any error::", error);
}
```

Comment: i tried it but the data from the `.env` is still undefined even after the `writeFile()`

Comment: @SyakhiskAl-azmi This should work! check the `.env` file if it has the  values of `let file` string? It's probably how you are reading values from `.env` file. Please update that as well in the question to have more context.

Comment: yes it should've worked. the data is inputted to the .env but i think my problem is that i loaded the `.env` is constant and i still couldn't find a way to reload it. thanks!

Comment: I assume you are using `dontenv` for environment variables, and you suspected right it will not reload the `.env` file and assign variables (if `.env` is changed in the middle of some code). A way to do this: [overriding the env variables listed here](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv#what-happens-to-environment-variables-that-were-already-set). Also please do consider accepting one of the answers as they solve the promise problem mentioned in your question. Good luck! 

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is to ONLY use promise-based asynchronous operations inside your `.then()` so you can properly chain all promises and then the higher level `await` will wait for everything.  In this case, you can use `return fs.promises.writeFile(...)` (instead of `fs.writeFile(...)`) because `fs.promises.writefile(...)` returns a promise and will then properly chain with the parent promise.

```
(async () => {

...

  if (process.env.IG_USERNAME && process.env.IG_PASSWORD) {
    console.log(`Used as ${chalk.green(process.env.IG_USERNAME)}`);
  } else {
    console.log(`\nInstagram account data is not yet put in \nInputting in...`);

    await inquirer.prompt(questions).then((answers) => {
      let file = `IG_USERNAME=${answers.username}\nIG_PASSWORD=${answers.password}\n#ONLINE_MODE=true`;
      return fs.promises.writeFile(".env", file);  
    });
  }

  await login();

...

})();
```

Or, simplified a little more:

```
(async () => {

...

  if (process.env.IG_USERNAME && process.env.IG_PASSWORD) {
    console.log(`Used as ${chalk.green(process.env.IG_USERNAME)}`);
  } else {
    console.log(`\nInstagram account data is not yet put in \nInputting in...`);

    const answers = await inquirer.prompt(questions);
    const file = `IG_USERNAME=${answers.username}\nIG_PASSWORD=${answers.password}\n#ONLINE_MODE=true`;
    await fs.promises.writeFile(".env", file);  
  }

  await login();

...

})();
```

Comment: i tried both example but the next statement/function seems to be executed first, even when i do `console.log(process.env.IG_USERNAME)` it still gives me `undefined`

Comment: i think i found the problem. it is not about the promises, it is about the .env file that i require at the top of the program so it wouldn't be change until i required it again in the next run of the program.